# how can i write a file data by read chunk chunk and write to channel in netty?

Tags: java, file-io, netty, heap-memory

i used netty 3.6 and i want to write a file data to a channel by any region and also with encryption 
i write a file data with FileRegion on a channel and dont have any problem and worked as fine and dont eat my RAM  but i want to read chunk chunk for encypted (by RC4)(chunk size is 512) befor wirte to channel , i used this code:

```
if (e.getChannel().isWritable()) {

    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);

    byte[] data = new byte[512];

         for (int i = 512; i < file.length(); i += 512) {

                        fin.read(data);
                        index_range += 512;
                        e.getChannel().write(ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(RC4.encrypte(data)));

                    }

                    int remain_len=(int)(file.length() - index_range);
                    if(remain_len>0){
                    data = new byte[remain_len];
                    fin.read(data);
                    e.getChannel().write(ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(RC4.encrypte(data)));
                    }
        fin.close();

     }
```

but i get **Exception in thread "pool-5-thread-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space** , i also used **RandomAccessFile** class but problem is as same , how can i resolved this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ChunkedWriteHandler and ChunkedNioFile. Then you can intercept the produced ChannelBuffer and do the encryption on the fly.

Comment: Thanks @normanm , i search for see any example to do this but i can not find any , can you show me your explain in a example code please

Comment: https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/3/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/http/file/HttpStaticFileServerHandler.java#L172

Comment: Thanks a lot netty master

Comment: @NormanMaurer The example is not found. Can you please share a new link.

Answer (score 0):

@normanm, The example you give used ChunkedFile in server side, can I use ChunkedFile when I posted a request?